# Auto add spaces in table cell / justify text to full width

Tags: tables, spacing, align, cell

I have a longtable:

```
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{longtable}{p{.3\textwidth} p{.675\textwidth}}
    \normalbs{MyTitle} \\
    [1.5ex]
    key                                 & value\\
```

I want the key to be justified to full cell width but only for certain cells.

For example:

[image]

should be:

[image]

**Edit:**

Font used is BentonSans (BentonSans-Light)

Comment: Why don't you use three columns if you want to do that?

Comment: because I only have this problem at some rows.

Comment: Then probably you just don't see it in the other rows. But you could of course use some code aligning it at the `-` in every cell.

Comment: for the example above I used `\hspace` of course. I have only few cells like the above with dates, others are just text, so I only need to align these with the dates. But its not a solution to manually add `\hspace` to every cell which contains dates in the first column. One can use `\justify` for normal text to get what I need but its not working for my example.

Comment: And what prevents you to switch to three columns?

Comment: the table is a bit to big to edit it. As described I need exactly the solution I tried to explain.

Comment: you make it very hard to help as you have shown no input related to the output.  This seems to be a bad choice of font, in most fonts used in tables the digits are all the same width so that `11` is as wide as `02` and everything lines up

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes you are right, I edited the question and added the font which is used. It seems to be font-related problem.

Comment: Also please fix your example so it produces the 2-line table as shown in the image, otherwise how can anyone test answers, the font seems to be commercial so I can not test but check if it has "lining figures" or "table figures" or some such in which case using that option would solve the problem. Do you have to use that font for that column?

Comment: thats the problem, I have to use this font..... I will upload another example what I need

Comment: The font is not suitable for table use (unless it has a font feature to select table digits, are you sure it has not?) otherwise just edit the file to change `-` to `hfill-\hfill` in that column.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I will use `\hfill ` as a workaround. Maybe I'll get a better idea how to get the result I need (with this font). You should post your comment as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most font families have available "lining figures" or "table figures" or some such in which case using that option would solve the problem as `11` would have the same width as `02`.

If the font does not have such digits available, you could edit the file to change `-` to`hfill-\hfill` in that column.